# Mnesia can't create tables when ran by Yaws, but can when ran from the Erlang shell

Tags: web, erlang, mnesia, yaws, erlang-shell

I have a .yaws file which invokes the `setup/0` function from the `authenticate` module I wrote, which I've placed in the `ebin` directory. When I call `authenticate:setup/0` from the Erlang shell, it creates a table just fine, but when I load something.yaws in the browser, which calls the `authenticate:setup/0` function, it returns `{aborted,{bad_type,users,disc_copies,nonode@nohost}}` (something.yaws just returns the return value of `authenticate:setup/0` embedded in html for debugging purposes).

Here's the `setup/0` function:

```
setup() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(users, [{type, set}, {record_name, user}, {disc_copies, [node()]}, {attributes, record_info(fields, user)}]).
```

and here's the `user` record:

```
-record(user, {username, hashed_pw, salt}).
```

(I have tried calling it from the Erlang shell after I've tried it in the browser, so that couldn't have interfered with it.)

If I run `yaws --mnesiadir /usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/mnesia/`, I get

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V8.1  (abort with ^G)
1> 
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Nov-2016::00:04:49 ===
Yaws: Using config file /etc/yaws/yaws.conf

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Nov-2016::00:04:49 ===
Yaws: Using global subconfig file /etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost.conf

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Nov-2016::00:04:49 ===
Ctlfile : /home/username/.yaws/yaws/default/CTL

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Nov-2016::00:04:49 ===
Yaws: Listening to 0.0.0.0:8080 for <1> virtual servers:
 - http://localhost:8080 under /usr/share/yaws/www
rd(user, {username, hashed_pw, salt}).
user
2> mnesia:create_schema([node()]), mnesia:start(), mnesia:create_table(users, [{type, set}, {record_name, user}, {disc_copies, [node()]}, {attributes, record_info(fields, user)}]).
{aborted,{bad_type,users,disc_copies,nonode@nohost}}
```

If I run the same erlang code in the Erlang shell started with `erl -mnesia dir '"/usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/mnesia/"'`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run Yaws, pass the command-line option `--mnesiadir dir` to tell it where you want it to store mnesia data. The `dir` argument of the option should be the pathname of the directory where you want the data to live. For example, passing `--mnesiadir /tmp` will cause Yaws to store mnesia data in the `/tmp` directory.

BTW, you can see the same error with the Erlang shell without Yaws if you pass it an mnesia `dir` option that sets the mnesia data directory to something nonexistent:

```
$ erl -mnesia dir '"/xyzfoo"'
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.1  (abort with ^G)
1> rd(user, {username, hashed_pw, salt}).
user
2> mnesia:create_schema([node()]), mnesia:start(), mnesia:create_table(users, [{type, set}, {record_name, user}, {disc_copies, [node()]}, {attributes, record_info(fields, user)}]).
{aborted,{bad_type,users,disc_copies,nonode@nohost}}
```

Here, we assume there's no such directory `/xyzfoo`. The first Erlang shell command defines the same `user` record you're using, and the second command performs the same steps as your `authenticate:setup/0` function. As shown, it returns the same error you're seeing with Yaws.

Note that the unusual quoting shown here for the directory name, `'"/xyzfoo"'`, needed for passing the option properly to the Erlang shell (on typical UNIX-based systems, anyway), isn't necessary for the Yaws `--mnesiadir` option. Also note that the Erlang option is a single hyphen followed by two words, `mnesia` and `dir`, followed by the quoted directory name, whereas for Yaws the option is one word `mnesiadir` preceded by two hyphens and followed by a plain directory name.

EDIT: if after setting the mnesia dir for Yaws you're still seeing problems, it's because you're trying to create your schema after mnesia is already running. When Yaws sees the `--mnesiadir` option, it starts the mnesia application. You should, therefore, either create your schema before you run Yaws, or stop mnesia before creating your schema. Change your `authenticate:setup/0` function to the following, and it will work from Yaws:

```
setup() ->
    mnesia:stop(),
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(users, [{type, set}, {record_name, user}, {disc_copies, [node()]}, {attributes, record_info(fields, user)}]).
```

Comment: I tried `yaws --mnesiadir DIR`, which still gave me the original error, even though it should have worked, then I tried `erl -mnesia dir '"DIR"'`, which did work (DIR represents the same directory in both cases). The output of yaws doesn't fit into a comment so I'll edit it into my main post.